# gnuplot wxt interactivity in c++

Tags: c++, gnuplot, user-interaction

i need help programmatically plot graphs using Gnuplot.

I have N graphs I want to plot each on a different window.
I currently generate a string containing a gnuplot script, where every plot call comes after a "`set terminal wxt n`", with n=0,1,...,N.

The problem is the active window is always the Nth, then the interactivity is disabled on the other N-1.

What can I do to re-gain the zoom/grid control? Why the control is not on the current focused window?
Thank you very much for your attention.

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation (`help wxt`):

> The active plot window (the one selected by `set term wxt <n>`) is
>    interactive.

The only way to regain `zoom`/`focus` control on the n'th plot is via a `set term wxt n`.  You can play various tricks though -- one trick is to use `bind` to bind the window number to a key:

```
bind 1 "set term wxt 1; raise"
bind 2 "set term wxt 2; raise"
```

This will reset the focus on the given plot number.  `raise` may or may not work (it doesn't seem to work for me currently).  If raising doesn't work, then consult the `help raise` for some ideas as to why. Of course, this only works if you have less than 11 plots to create -- If you have more then you need to get more creative with your key bindings I suppose.

Comment: ok, bind could be the solution. The problem is that after having setted n-th terminal, the plotted graph changes to the previusly active one. in other words, if i have a graph in wxt 0 and another different graph in wxt 1, after having setted wxt 0 from wxt 1, in the window id:0 appears the graph which is drawn in window id:1. The 2 windows show the same graph. Any idea? thank you in advance.